# React: background image not loading when deployed to server

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack-2

I am using webpack to transpile my reactjs code. When I run it locally on webpack dev server, I can see my background image. However when I deploy it to the server the image doesn't show. I figure it must be some kind of path issue.

css

```
.centerbg {
    background: url(/images/centerbg.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

jsx

```
<div className="centerbg">

</div>
```

webpack loader

```
        {
            test: /\.(woff|ttf|eot|svg|png|jpg)(\?v=[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                limit: 10000
            }
        }
```

File paths

```
build/main.js
images/centerbg.jpg
index.html
```

Comment: The path needs to be relative to the app's root directory so that when all your JSX gets transpiled into a single JS file, the paths still remain the same. So it should ideally be relative where your index.html is. In your express server, you need to set the path from which all requests are based (by setting where `app.use('/'....);` gets resources from[that's the base URL for the whole app]) then in your JSX you can just use `url(images/potato.jpg)` and when it gets transpiled the resulting JS file will be in that same root directory so the path still works (no slash in front of the path)

Comment: I'm not using express. This is IIS hosted in production. In development I am using webpack dev server.  background: url(..\images\centerbg.jpg) or background: url(images/centerbg.jpg) don't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug usually dued to [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path) config not being explicitely declared.

Set it to the path where your assets will be served from. For basic scenarios this is enough:

```
output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    //...
},
```

Comment: I do have my publicPath defined. Its  publicPath: 'build' in my case as my assets are being served from there.